# Sort array of type Int in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tableview

I have an array of type String which I want to convert to Int and sort it by ascending/descending order

```
 var prices = ["100", "200", "90", "", "", "300", "100"]
    lazy var intPrices = prices.compactMap { Int($0) }

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Ive seen this sorted() method on the web and I`d like to use this approach
please help me out

This is the func that I'm trying to implement and attach to a button:

```
@objc func sortPrices() {
intPrices.sorted() { $0.intPrices > $1.intPrices } 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside of `sortPrices()` to achieve the desired functionality
(I've assumed that an empty `String` will have a value of zero):

```
 let prices = ["100", "200", "90", "", "", "300", "100"]
 let intPrices: [Int] = prices.compactMap {Int($0) ?? 0}.sorted(by: < )
 print(intPrices)
```

Comment: The use of compactMap and a nil coalescing operator providing a default value is pointless. If you are never returning nil just use map. Btw you are using the wrong operator if your intent is to sort it descending

Answer (score 0):

`intPrices` is an array of `Int` so the compiler likely tells you:

> Value of type 'Int' has no member 'intPrice'

this is enough:

```
var prices = ["100", "200", "90", "", "", "300", "100"]
var intPrices = prices.compactMap { Int($0) }.sorted()
print(intPrices) // [90, 100, 100, 200, 300]
```

And by the way this is the proper way to declare a lazy var:

```
lazy var intPrices = prices.compactMap { Int($0) }
```

Comment: no need to use a closure